# Can I use typescript inside js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, vue.js, type-conversion

I'm trying to initiated Vue3 application from inside Angularjs. It is possible export main typescript file to my current project using script tag and use inside my js file?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You have to transpile the ts file to js using tsc command from typescript library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript